# SonarLint Eclipse connecting to SonarQube server gives "No storage for server 'sonar'. Please update."

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarqube5.3, sonarlint-eclipse

My company upgraded to SonarQube 5.3. This requires changing from the SonarQube plugin for Eclipse to SonarLint. I regret that upgrade because my project quality profile contains 494 rules and only 12 are from Squid, so we have a massive project to make SonarLint in Eclipse at all useful. But I'm trying to install SonarLint 2.0.2 on my PC anyway. When I try to test the connection to the SQ server I get an error in the SonarLint Console. What's the problem?

```
No storage for server 'sonar'. Please update.
Fail to request https://sonar.forge.mycompany.com:9000/api/system/status
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request https://sonar.forge.mycompany.com:9000/api/system/status
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.doCall(HttpConnector.java:202)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.get(HttpConnector.java:144)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.call(HttpConnector.java:133)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.connected.SonarLintWsClient.rawGet(SonarLintWsClient.java:98)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.connected.validate.ServerVersionAndStatusChecker.fetchServerInfos(ServerVersionAndStatusChecker.java:97)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.connected.validate.ServerVersionAndStatusChecker.checkVersionAndStatus(ServerVersionAndStatusChecker.java:61)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.connected.validate.ServerVersionAndStatusChecker.checkVersionAndStatus(ServerVersionAndStatusChecker.java:51)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.WsHelperImpl.validateConnection(WsHelperImpl.java:50)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.WsHelperImpl.validateConnection(WsHelperImpl.java:45)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.server.Server.testConnection(Server.java:244)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.ui.internal.server.wizard.ServerConnectionTestJob.run(ServerConnectionTestJob.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:192)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:286)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:243)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:205)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:80)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.doCall(HttpConnector.java:199)
    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 3):

Port `9000` is the default *HTTP*-Port for SonarQube. SonarLint proposes `https://` when configuring a new server connection.

So, if you just change

```
https://sonar.forge.mycompany.com:9000
```

to

```
http://sonar.forge.mycompany.com:9000
```

and you probably can connect SonarLint with SonarQube.

Comment: That sounds good. I'll check that out when I go back to using SonarLint. For now I'm staying with running Sonar outside of Eclipse. Most of our rules aren't Squid yet, so SonarLint is almost useless. :(

Answer (score 0):

You're focused on the wrong thing.  The "No Storage..." message won't stop it from working, I get that all the time with the latest sonar/sonar lint.

Have a look at your server configuration.  It looks like there's a protocol mismatch...

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request https://sonar.forge.mycompany.com:9000/api/system/status
.
.
.
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```